# will restAssured work with rest input parameters coming from excel sheet? Has anyone tried it?

Tags: excel, rest, rest-assured

I have been asked by my boss to find a tool or design one for testing rest services hosted in cloud environment. He also asked me if I can read the input data from excel sheet so that other junior members can write tests in excel. I have created keyword driven framework using Apache poi so I know how to read data from excel in Java program. I have also worked on httpClient, so I can tie these together. But I am hearing a lot about rest assured and want to know can I use rest assured where input can be read from excel. Is it worth spending time on? Also with cloud infrastructure which approach is best? Thanks.

Comment: did you find a good example that uses excel data source?

Answer (score 1):

You can safely proceed with your boss's request, since there is no link between Excel Inputs & REST assured framework, as both of them are separate jars.

You can read test inputs/outputs from excel and use them in REST assured. REST assured provides an easy to implement REST testing DSL with BDD flavor.

The following link gives you a quick getting started tutorial.

http://www.hascode.com/2011/10/testing-restful-web-services-made-easy-using-the-rest-assured-framework/

Comment: You've given only for GET method not for POST method,Can you please post blog on POST method.

Comment: @RajeshOm your question is not clear. GET and POST method do not have anything related to excel. You will use any available library to read from excel e.g., poi

Comment: ,i didn't ask above question,i've read your blog post,it is showing only GET method , no example of POST methods as well as your answer is not matching with above question.

Comment: Well the question is about REST assured framework along with excel reading jars, which is addressed by my answer. For POST examples in rest-assured framework you can refer to numerous examples in its GitHub repository: https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured